# how to send xml file to android application using c#

Tags: c#, android, dom, xml-parsing

I want to send data from c#(aspx) to android application.

My c#(aspx)page have code which is called from android application, that retrieve values from sql database and put it into an XML file using DataSet and return back xml file to android application.

The code for retrieving data from database and storing in xml is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

class ExecuteXmlReader
{
public static void Main()
{
String sConnection = "server=.\\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=employee";
SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sConnection);
mySqlConnection.Open();

// Get the same data through the provider.
SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FirstName,LastName,Title,City from employees", sConnection);
DataSet myDataSet2 = new DataSet();myDataSet2.DataSetName = "Region";
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet2);


// Write data to files: data1.xml and data2.xml for comparison.

myDataSet2.WriteXml("c:/temp/employees.xml");
mySqlConnection.Close();
}

}
```

now how do I return this xml file to android application. In android I am using `DOM XML parser` to extract data from file.

Please help me in this.. any tips will be accepted.

Comment: u need to get xml using dataset.getxml() and write function to return dataset.call this method from android application using httpclient then use DOM parser for xml parsing in android.hope this helps

Comment: will you please elaborate please. and how can we call a particular function from android.?

if we need to call a page then we can call it using

`final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer("http://10.0.2.2:8347/LoginPage/Default.aspx");`

but how to call a function which can return some values.!

Comment: build webservice.then you need to have webmethod that can be called thr android code.

Comment: @SharadMhaske web service is deprecated.. when i searched for it... i found that WCF is now used. do you know how to create one such WCF. any tips or links will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this it has sample wcf webservice with consumption in android-http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx.hope this helps you